# Can someone explain why this summation is equal?

Tags: summation

Can someone explain to me why this is equal?

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n i = \sum_{i = 1}^n (n - i + 1) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} (n - i)$$

Comment: What do you get when you try it with $n=5$?

Comment: In the left most you sum $\;1+2+3+\ldots+n\;$ , in the central one you sum $\;n+(n-1)+\ldots+3+2+1\;$ , and  the rightmost one is just a nicer form to write the central one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write out their sums:

The first one is $1+2+\dotsb+(n-1) + n$.

The second one is $n + (n-1) + \dotsb +2+1$.

The third one is again $n + (n-1) + \dotsb +2+1$.

Comment: Oh so the second and third were just backwards, but it still adds up the same, thanks a bunch :)

Comment: @kalvin, yeah if you ever have a question about summations or sequences, it's never a bad idea to just start writing out the terms.